# Error when running +NORMALIZE WHITESPACE in doctest on Mac terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

When I run the following doctest in Mac terminal

```
>>> import sys
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
[1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9]
>>> sys.stdout.write("This text contains weird spacing.")
... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
This text contains weird spacing.
```

I get the following output with a "33" at the end, which makes this test fail. 
Any idea how to correct this?

```
File "test2.txt", line 8, in test2.txt
Failed example:
    sys.stdout.write("This text contains weird spacing.")
    # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
Expected:
    This text contains weird spacing.
Got:
    This text contains weird spacing.33
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in test2.txt
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write` is a function that returns the amount of characters that was written. *Prior to returning*, it writes the argument to the console. So when you call `sys.stdout.write("This text contains weird spacing.")` the string is written to the console, and then the length of the string (`33`) is returned. That is why doctest is getting `This text contains weird spacing.33`.

I suggest you use the `print` method instead:

```
>>> print("This text contains weird spacing.")
... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
This text contains weird spacing.
```

If you must use `sys.stdout.write` you can capture the returned value, that way it would be ignored by `doctest`. Like this:

```
>>> ln = sys.stdout.write("This text contains weird spacing.")
... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
This text contains weird spacing.
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried both, and the  '>>> ln = sys.stdout.write("This text contains weird spacing.")' worked, while the '>>> print("This text contains weird spacing.")' didn't.

Comment: @AtxTom in my opinion using `print` is cleaner. I can't imagine why it isn't working for you. You can execute the example [here](http://goo.gl/IWrEYC).